# apache httpd log : filter out lines containing a string

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm trying to get TLS < 1.2 requests from a custom httpd log file, the config is:

```
SetEnvIf SSL_PROTOCOL "TLSv1.2" dontlog
CustomLog logs/TLSv_TSV \
"%h\t\
%{SSL_PROTOCOL}x\t\
%{SSL_CIPHER}x\t\
%{User-Agent}i\t\
%r" env=!dontlog
```

but "TLSv1.2" entries are still logged.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik setEnvIf only has access to a handful of variables.

Try with the expression engine instead:

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{SSL_PROTOCOL} == 'TLSv1.2'" dontlog
```

Comment: Wow, we're almost there!<br><br>
Type of lines I had before your suggestion:<br>
TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; M2007J22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)<br><br>

After, I get what I want, say:<br>
TLSv1   AES256-SHA      Guzzle/5.3.1 curl/7.29.0 PHP/5.4.16<br><br>

Oddly enough, I still get that (and only that) type of line I wouldn't expect:<br>
TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     -       -<br>
TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     -       -<br>
[...]<br><br>

It seems like a specific bug, what do you think?